# Angular doesn't update the view on arrival of new data

Tags: angular

I've defined a search-input field in the navbar:
`<input type="search" class="form-control" [formControl]="search" placeholder="search" aria-label="search">`

In its controller I subscribe for changes and forward them to the search service:

```
this.search
  .valueChanges
  .subscribe(v => {
    this.searchService.setSearchValue(v);

    if (this.changeDetectorRef !== null && this.changeDetectorRef !== undefined &&
      !(this.changeDetectorRef as ViewRef).destroyed) {
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
  });
}
```

The search service holds the value and other components can request it.

```
searchValue: Subject<string>;

getSearchValue(): Observable<string> {
    return this.searchValue;
}

setSearchValue(searchValue: string) {
    this.searchValue.next(searchValue);
}
```

In my data view, I display all data filtered by the search-value:

```
<div *ngIf="(services | search:searchValue) as result">
    <div *ngFor="let service of result">
        {{ service.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
this.searchService.getSearchValue().subscribe(value => {
    console.log("new search value: " + value);
    this.searchValue = value;
});
```

The view doesn't update on the first keystroke however, and only updates itself after the second one.

I know that the correct search value arrives at the component as the console.log contains the expected value, but the view is nevertheless not updated. I've also tried `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and `searchPipe.transform(this.services, value)` in my view but without success.

Could anyone tell me what went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you perhaps make a small project on jsfiddle or some other site where the behavior could be inspected?

Comment: I can't see an immediate error with your approach. Do note that you don't *have* to create a variable in your component class and subscribe manually, the `async` pipe can help with that; i.e. `<ng-container *ngIf="searchValue | async as result"> <div *ngFor="let service of result"> <!-- and so on -->`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, unfortunately nothing worked for me. Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzpt44) to my problem

Answer (score 1):

Firstly. you don't have to use such a piece of code:

```js
      if (this.changeDetectorRef !== null && this.changeDetectorRef !== undefined &&
          !(this.changeDetectorRef as ViewRef).destroyed) {
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }
```

I suppose sometimes you catch an exception, that's why you don't unsubscribe from `this.search.valueChanges` or you have logic that works very strange.

Try to use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`, difference being that `Subject` don't store the last emitted value, whereas `BehaviorSubjects` do.
Maybe one of your component or service initializes faster than other components, and your `Subject` already fired value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your doing the below code in ngonInit

```
this.searchService.getSearchValue().subscribe(value => {
    console.log("new search value: " + value);
    this.searchValue = value;

    // Run the change detection here 
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
});
```